# Email harvester in Python: How to improve performance?

Tags: python, performance, email, python-multithreading

I have found a program called "Best Email Extractor" http://www.emailextractor.net/. The website says it is written in Python. I tried to write a similar program. The above program extracts about 300 - 1000 emails per minute. My program extracts about 30-100 emails per hour. Could someone give me tips on how to improve the performance of my program? I wrote the following:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import urllib2
import re
import lxml.html as lxml
import time
import threading


def getUrls(start):

    urls = []
    try:
        dom = lxml.parse(start).getroot()
        dom.make_links_absolute()

        for url in dom.iterlinks():
            if not '.jpg' in url[2]:
                if not '.JPG' in url[2]:
                    if not '.ico' in url[2]:
                        if not '.png' in url[2]:
                            if not '.jpeg' in url[2]:
                                if not '.gif' in url[2]:
                                    if not 'youtube.com' in url[2]:
                                        urls.append(url[2])
    except:
        pass

    return urls

def getURLContent(urlAdresse):

    try:
      url = urllib2.urlopen(urlAdresse)
      text = url.read()
      url.close()
      return text
    except:
        return '<html></html>'

def harvestEmail(url):
    text = getURLContent(url)

    emails = re.findall('[\w\-][\w\-\.]+@[\w\-][\w\-\.]+[a-zA-Z]{1,4}', text)

    if emails:
        if saveEmail(emails[0]) == 1:
            print emails[0]

def saveUrl(url):

    connection = sql.connect('url.db')

    url = (url, )

    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM urladressen WHERE adresse = ?', url)
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        if(data[0] == 0):
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO urladressen VALUES(NULL, ?)', url)
            return 1
        return 0

def saveEmail(email):
    connection = sql.connect('emails.db')
    email = (email, )

    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM addresse WHERE email = ?', email)
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        if(data[0] == 0):
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO addresse VALUES(NULL, ?)', email)
            return 1
    return 0

def searchrun(urls):
    for url in urls:
        if saveUrl(url) == 1:
            #time.sleep(0.6)
            harvestEmail(url)
            print url
            urls.remove(url)
            urls = urls + getUrls(url)

urls1 = getUrls('http://www.google.de/#hl=de&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=DVD')
urls2 = getUrls('http://www.google.de/#hl=de&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Jolie')
urls3 = getUrls('http://www.finanzen.net')
urls4 = getUrls('http://www.google.de/#hl=de&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Party')
urls5 = getUrls('http://www.google.de/#hl=de&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Games')
urls6 = getUrls('http://www.spiegel.de')
urls7 = getUrls('http://www.kicker.de/')
urls8 = getUrls('http://www.chessbase.com')
urls9 = getUrls('http://www.nba.com')
urls10 = getUrls('http://www.nfl.com')


try:
    threads = []
    urls = (urls1, urls2, urls3, urls4, urls5, urls6, urls7, urls8, urls9, urls10)

    for urlList in urls:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=searchrun, args=(urlList, )).start()
        threads.append(thread)
    print threading.activeCount()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
except RuntimeError:
    print RuntimeError
```

Comment: -1 And what would you use those emails for my friend? inviting people to your party ???

Comment: It is not so much about the emails. I am interested in how to make the fetching of the websites faster.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think many people are going to help you harvest emails. It's a generally detested activity.

Regarding the performance bottlenecks in your code, you need to find out where the time is going by profiling. At the lowest level, replace each of your functions with a dummy that does no processing but returns valid output; so the email collector could return a list of the same address 100 times (or however many are in these URL results). That will show you which function is costing you time.

Things that stick out:

1. Get the files behind the URLs from the server beforehand; if you spam Google every time you run the script, they could well block you. Reading from disk is faster than requesting the files from the internet and can be done separately and concurrently.
2. The database code is creating a new connection for each call to saveEmail etc, which will spend most of its time doing handshaking and authentication. Better to have an object that keeps the connection alive between calls, or better yet to insert multiple records at once.
3. Once the network and database issues are done, the regex could probably do with `\b` around it so that the matching does less backtracking.
4. A series of if not 'foo' in str: then if not 'blah' in str ... is poor coding. Extract the final segment once and check it against multiple values by creating a `set` or even `frozenset` of all the non-permitted values like `ignoredExtensions = set([jpg,png,gif])` and comparing with that like `if not extension in ignoredExtensions`. Note also that converting extension to lower case first will mean less checking and work whether it is jpg or JPG.
5. Finally, consider running the same script without threading on multiple commandlines. There is no real need to have the threading inside the script except for coordinating the different url lists. Frankly it would be far simpler to just have a set of url lists in files, and start a separate script to work on each. Let the OS do the multithreading, it is better at it.

Comment: … and even most of the people who _don't_ detest email harvesting are going to hate you, because they make their money doing it, and don't want competition for the pool of small companies that can be scammed into wasting money paying for spam to be sent out in their names…

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I am now using multiprocessing instead of threads. It improved the performance quite a bit. I read that Python's threading should be avoided. I will try the technique described by Phil H under point 5.